# Homeomorphic compact spaces have homeomorphic boundaries

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be open bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. How to show that $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are not homeomorphic whenever $\delta X$ is not homeomorphic to $\delta Y$?

I know that if $\delta X$ is not homeomorphic to $\delta Y$, then there does not exist continuous bijection from $\delta X$ to $\delta Y$ which has continuous inverse. Then how to show that $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are not homeomorphic using these facts.

P.S. Bar means Closure.

Comment: Here's a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$: $X=(-1,+1)$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic, and yet $\delta X = \{-1,+1\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\delta Y = \emptyset$. Similar examples exist in $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely an open ball and the whole space.

Comment: @LeeMosher: I was thinking along those lines too. I thought of an open disk in the plane and an open disk minus a radial slit. They are homeomorphic, but the corresponding boundaries are a circle and a circle with a sticker, which are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @LeeMosher, then how if X and Y are both proper subsets?

Comment: You can still take the same $X$ and $Y = (1,+ \infty)$.

Comment: Maybe this can be repaired by requiring their closures to be compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: This being said these are not counter-examples to your exact question, because $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @CaptainLama Not any more, as of the recent edit. They used to be, though.

Comment: @KlausDraeger Ah I didn't notice there was an edit, my bad.

Comment: @All, sorry I forgot to put some conditions. I have edited the questions.

Comment: This is false, as shown by your radial slit example.